# Include child elements with xpointer element() scheme

Tags: xml, docbook, docbook-5, xpointer

I am trying to include all child elements (sections) of an element from a.xml into b.xml with xi:include. Both XML files are valid docbook 5 files.

a.xml

```
<chapter xml:id="TheChapter">
    <section>
        <title>section 1</title>
    </section>
    <section>
        <title>section 2</title>
    </section>
    <section>
        <title>section 3</title>
    </section>
</chapter>
```

b.xml

```
<section>
      <xi:include href="a.xml" xpointer="element(/TheChapter/*)"/>
</section>
```

I am using XMLMind which reports an error.

```
cannot parse inclusion directive: cannot parse XPointer "element(/TheChapter/*)": "/TheChapter/*", XPointer element() scheme syntax error
```

Is my use of element() scheme not correct?

Answer (score 5):

Your use of the [`element()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xptr-element/#model) scheme is not correct.

- The first portion of the expression identifying an element via its ID should not start with a forward slash.
- Wildcards (`*`) cannot be used. The "child sequence" can contain forward slashes and numbers only.

This is a valid expression:

```
element(TheChapter/1)
```

It will select the first child of the element identified by the `TheChapter` ID. What you want cannot be done using the `element()` scheme.

---

You could use the [`xpointer()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xptr-xpointer/) scheme:

```
xpointer(id('TheChapter')/*)
```

The `xpointer()` scheme never became a W3C recommendation (it's still just a draft) and it is not widely implemented.

XMLmind XML Editor does support a subset of `xpointer()`. Here is a mailing list post with some more details: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.editors.xxe.general/10220.

Comment: it's 2022, `xpointer()` is still *not widely implemented* :(

Answer (score 0):

The following usage works fine:

```html
<xi:include href="a.xml" xpointer="xmlns(db=http://docbook.org/ns/docbook) xpointer(id('TheChapter')/db:section)"/>
```

Or

```html
<xi:include href="a.xml" xpointer="xmlns(db=http://docbook.org/ns/docbook) xpointer(id('TheChapter')/*)"/>
```